# Force JS cache clearing without server-side coding

Tags: javascript, caching

I'm looking to clear the cache on some JavaScript files on my login page. Our web language is pretty archaic, and I'm stuck using it. No PHP, Rails, or anything fun or fancy.

**Looking to clear cache on JS files**
1. I can't use server-side code.
2. I can't manually append a query string.
3. I found the meta tags mentioned, but noticed that strictly referred the caching the HTML.

My only thought was to use JavaScript in the header to manipulate the text of the HTML document before it loads the files in the  tags that occur further down the page. Though I was unable to get this to work successfully. Any ideas?

Comment: What about using [AMD with something like RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)?

Comment: Every web language, as archaic as it might be, allows you to send HTTP header. What language is it?! Show us your serverside code! No need to switch to another language.

Comment: Show us what you tried to manipulate the HTML source.

Comment: @Bergi the way our web framework is set up, it doesn't allow the use of server side code, unless someone logs in and sets up a session. They're stuck at the login screen with old JS. Good call though, I'll add the HTML source.

Comment: @edhedges Will look into this briefly.

Comment: Send a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header from the server. You shouldn’t have to change any code to do that, just configuration of some server or another.

Comment: @false How would this work if the static files are cached on the clients browser?

Comment: @edhedges: What, are they cached already? I’m really not sure what this is going to be used for. If they are, move the files around or something. It’s like a querystring, but more tedious.

Comment: Would the following hypothetical work? I write a small script that adds the `<script>` tags to the end of the HTML document. Also, @false I'm trying to avoid tedium and manual intervention. This package is also served over several hundred servers. I'd really like to avoid additional setup on customer boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you currently have something like this in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/js/script.js"></script>
```

If you can't change that, you're stuck. The browser is going to load that as soon as it sees the tag. There's not a reliable way to stop the browser from doing that, or to manipulate the tag before the browser acts on it.

If you can change it, though, the most obvious solution to me is to take it out, and instead dynamically inject a script tag with a cache-busting URL. For example (untested, but you get the idea):

```
<script>
  var scriptUrl = "/site/js/script.js",
      cacheBustingUrl = scriptUrl + "?" + Date.now(),
      newScriptElement = document.createElement("script")
  ;

  newScriptElement.setAttribute("src", cacheBustingUrl);
  document.body.appendChild(newScriptElement);
</script>
```

This should append a new script element like `<script src="/site/js/script.js?1404918388711"></script>` to the end of the page, which the browser will load like any other script tag.

If you already have jQuery, by the way, this is a little more succinct:

```
<script>
  var scriptUrl = "/site/js/script.js",
      cacheBustingUrl = scriptUrl + "?" + Date.now()
  ;

  $("<script>").attr("src", cacheBustingUrl).appendTo(document.body);
</script>
```

Comment: Yea, and then it will fail when you put a function contained in that referenced script when you use it on iframe.onload - which is exactly why this is not a real solution...

Comment: @StefanSteiger Okay. Feel free to post an answer.